# Why is it that I am unable to format my pendrive in exfat using gparted?

Tags: 16.04, gparted, usb-drive

When I go to Gparted and try to format my pendrive to exfat,the option is greyed out and I am not able to select it however I can choose other file systems such as ext4,ntfs,etc. 
Why is that ?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @mikewhatever emmh...not really. Couldn't find anything in that post related to creating exfat

Comment: IMPORTANT POINT: Make sure to Unmount the disk first. Otherwise the options remain grayed out.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Gparted <strike>doesn't</strike>[UPD 210609] [support](http://gparted.org/features.php)  creation of exfat file systems. You can use `mkfs.exfat` utility from the terminal like:

```
sudo mkfs.exfat -n LABEL /dev/sdXn
```

Replace `LABEL` with the label that you want for your USB and `/dev/sdXn` with the partition id of your USB.

You will have to install `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` from the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) for the above to work;

```
 sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

**UPD 210609** is not true anymore, just install [exfatprogs](https://github.com/exfatprogs/exfatprogs)

Comment: Another alternative to Gparted if you don't want use a terminal is to use Kde Partition Manager. It still support (still) support exFAT. You can my post about it here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006553/143133

Comment: If you are using Gnome `Disk` application and the `exFat` option is still greyed out, intall `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` according to @Ron 's answer.

Comment: 2020 and still no support in Gparted for exfat lol ><

Comment: I had to use "Disks" to create a FAT partition, and only then run the `mkfs.exfat` command above.

Comment: @MehrdadSalimi 's comment worked well for me. I installed `exfat-utils` and `exfat-fuse` 
per @Ron 's instructions and then Gnome Disks had the option for `exFat` ungreyed and I was able to use it.

Comment: IMPORTANT POINT: Make sure to Unmount the disk first. Otherwise the options remain grayed out.

Comment: It seems this answer is now outdated: https://gparted.org/features.php shows exfat as supported if `exfatprogs` is installed. However, `exfatprogs` is only packaged for Ubuntu >= 20.10, so the gparted in Ubuntu 20.04 won't support it. But the one in 20.10 probably should. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 17):

**Workaround: use `gnome-disks`**

This is the default pre-installed disk manager tool on Ubuntu that shows on the Dash as "Disks".

You can also launch if from the terminal with:

```
gnome-disks
```

Ensure that you have the exfat backend installed:

```
sudo apt install exfat-utils
```

Then as of Ubuntu 18.04:

- Gears button
- Format Partition
- Type: "Other"
- Next
- exfat

[image]

[image]

[image]

The GUI was a bit different in older versions: [GUI tool for formating to exFAT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750681/gui-tool-for-formating-to-exfat/750687#750687)

This is the only non-archaic filesystem I could find that works natively on all of current Mac OS, Windows and Linux, what a world to live in.

Comment: In case Disks gives error, use Gparted first to format to fat32 for example, and then proceed as above for exFAT. OR, **for a stick or other drive with one single partition**, use Disk to select the drive in the left panel but then, instead of the gear button, go to the top right button and select "Format disk" and then "No partitioning (empty)", and then do as in the answer.

Comment: I don't have the option for exFAT available.

Comment: @rvcristiand is it grayed out or doesn't show at all? Which Ubuntu version? Can you check if the `exfat-utils` package is installed?

Comment: It was gray. Buy after install exfat-utils and exfat-fuse it works.

Comment: @rvcristiand awesome, I thought it was installed by default always, adding to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was also getting the same error in `gnome-disks`. You can switch if you want.

exFat was still greyed. However, I fixed by installing:
     `sudo apt install exfat-utils exfat-fuse`

Answer (score 3):

in Ubuntu 22.04 I was unable to install exfat-utils, but after I installed exfat-fuse and it pulled in a few other exfat items, gparted worked for exfat.  So, "sudo apt install exfat-fuse" should work.

Answer (score 3):

Using Ubuntu Disks app to format my USB stick to exFAT, and I couldn't install neceassary packages, asked GPT-4 and got this, and everything went well afterward:

**Install the newer exFAT support packages: In newer versions of Ubuntu (20.04 and later), the exfat-utils and exfat-fuse packages have been replaced by the exfatprogs package. You can install this package by running:**

```
sudo apt install exfatprogs
```

I installed and exFAT option got ungreyed

Answer (score 2):

While Gparted cannot handle exFAT format, beside other tools that can (Gnome Disks, KDE Partition Manager), there is also the USB Stick Formatter, part of the [`mintstick` tool](https://github.com/linuxmint/mintstick) (which includes both an USB Formatter and an USB Writter), and it covers exFAT format.

[image]

It is default in Linux Mint but can be installed in Ubuntu as deb from [packages.linuxmint.com](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/m/mintstick/) or [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/mintstick).

Comment: **Please comment why you down-vote and/or vote to delete/close. (Is that even possible for answers?)** - If it's because Linux Mint was mentioned, that shouldn't be a reason, as the tool is available for Ubuntu as many other 3rd party apps. - If it's because the answer is not about gparted: all answers here give alternatives to gparted.

Comment: Some people downvote without telling who they are and why they do it. I think it is a way to spread bad sentiment, a kind of trolling. Try to ignore it. Most of us appreciate what you and other people do to give advice and share tips.

Comment: @sudodus - It's even worse — I mean more interesting: this answer was marked for **deletion** - which is visible to me, but not to many others : [Meta: Why do I see a delete option under my answer (and how to find what's that about)?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18982/925128)

Comment: @sudodus - I see you are above 30k reputation, in comments under the meta question it is said that only 20k reputation users can cast deletes for answers. Do you see the delete option? Just curious.

Comment: No, the delete option only appears if the score is -1 or lower.  https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/trusted-user

Comment: Of course, this helps!