# Ubuntu installed on SSD 256GB but HDD 1 TB /dev/sda1 showing read only file system problem

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive

Unable to create a folder or copy/paste file in /dev/sda1 which is my HDD.
When I try to create a folder from the terminal it says **read-only file system**.
Using Ubuntu 18.04

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘Entertainment’: Read-only file system

Comment: What kind of filesystem is on your HDD?

Comment: how can i check this???

Comment: `sudo blkid` for instance. PLEASE don't post screenshots of text from a terminal. You can copy and paste text.

Comment: or `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE | grep sda1`

Comment: it is NTFS file system

Comment: @user2176338 are you dual-booting?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity no, booting only from SSD. I'm using HDD for only backup things.

Comment: Question is did Windows set hibernation flag on the NTFS. It does that with its fast start up setting. And updates turn fast start up back on. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: It came with Windows 10 then I formatted SSD and installed Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @user2176338 Can you make a backup of the data in that partition? Because I'd recommend that you format it again in EXT4. NTFS and linux don't mix well.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity it is completely empty right now.
can you tell me how to format it in EXT4?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity actually in windows, you just right click on the drive and format it but I don't know how to do it in Ubuntu.

Comment: In Ubuntu you can use Disks utility or GParted. [Here's an example](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089839/931617) with disks.

Comment: okay thanks
i just got this from disk -l command

`Device     Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G Microsoft basic data`

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity i used gnome-disks and formatted it.
It worked.
thanks!!! everyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: @Pilot6 yes i got the hint then schrodigerscatcuriosity suggested to format it with a disks utility.

Comment: You will lose all data if you fromat it. But if there is no Windows, then it is the best solution.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, but actually I had nothing on the disk so I just formatted it.
thanks for the help.